# How can I safely git rebase commit history in master

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

My new team has not been using git in the most efficient way and my lead asked me to clean up the repo. They all have been working off of master - not creating branches. There are many small commits in master. I created a new branch `bug_rebase_history` and rebased squashing commits until there was one commit per day. This decreased the commits in master from 465 to 180.

How can I create a merge request in the GitLab web interface that will merge this rebase in a way that won't just add the new squashed commits on top of the HEAD? Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: There is no "git web interface". Git is a command line tool. More to the point: if you merge, you will keep the existing history; that's what merging does. You'll have to force-push if you want to rewrite history like this.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but "one commit per time period" is a terrible model that will really make it hard to make effective use of your version control tool (e.g., you want to be able to revert isolated changes, which isn't possible if you're batching up a bunch of unrelated changes into a single commit).

Comment: First: having many commits with small changes must not be a bad practice. Actually it is rather a good practice to do it this way. Second: It is not clear what you did. If you squashed commits you likely worked on the master branch as long as you did not copy (cherry-picked) all commits to a new branch. "Merging a rebase" is not possible since it is the same branch. What you may mean is a fast-forward merge so that the two branches are pointing to the same commit. If you want to publish these changes on master, you need to do a force push.

Comment: By "git web interface" I mean GitLab. I usually use `git push --force-with-lease origin <branch name>:<branch name>`. I am on my own branch named `bug_rebase_master` I'm asking about how to merge it to remote master so that the changes are overridden in master

Comment: Don't.  Push back.  Small commits is a good thing.  It is (sometimes) better if they are on branches which are merged (but fast-forward merging is good, too, in which case you get commits on master), but there's no real benefit in trying to pull things out into branches after the fact.  And there's no benefit at all in squashing the merges into giant monstrosities.  Accept the current state of the repo but impose some discipline moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a merge request in the GitLab web interface that will merge this rebase in a way that won't just add the new squashed commits on top of the HEAD?

**It's not possible.**

The only way to *remove* commits from a branch is to `reset` the branch and then force push it back out. If you re-write a protected branch you will need to force push that branch out from a client tool (and perhaps temporarily give yourself permission to force-push the protected branch).

A Merge (or Pull) Request can bring (merge) in new commits, but cannot remove any commits from a branch.